# Technical reason of why you need to use Class::static_method() instead of Class->static_method() in PHP

Tags: php

I'd like to know if there's a technical reason of why PHP's designers decided to invoke a static method using `Class::static_method()` instead of `Class->static_method()` (like any other method).
Does the syntax change reflect any technical requirement?

I'm asking this because the syntax for every single other language I know to invoke a method is always the same, despite it being static or not.

Comment: it imitates C++ in that; it has 3 different ways to invoke methods: the dot for references and values, the arrow for pointers and the double colon for statics

Comment: @ratchetfreak does that make any easier to parse the code?

Answer (score 1):

Invocation of instance methods is not `Class->method()` but `$object->method()`. Additionally, semantics of the `->` operator is that it passes the instance of the class (vulgo: object) to the method in a hidden parameter; class methods differ from instance methods in that they, at best, have access to class attributes.